# WordPress , how can we get all js and css files that are shown in browser network monitoring

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

WP_Scripts and WP_Styles variables list all js and css files that are in queue , exact define is 'file that are hook before rendaring the page' . in some pages there are files that are load in page and browser network manitoring , manitor them , but they are not in queue list that this two global variable return .

how can we get all js and css files that are shown in browser network monitoring?

Comment: This is harder than you might think.  You'll get them _late_, because it's possible for them to be rendered in the footer based on conditions.  When do you need them? What will you do with them?

Answer (score 0):

This is a WordPress action hook which gives you all the URL's and you can separate from the array list.

```
 add_action('clean_url',function($url){
      return $url;
    });
```